# Why I can't use emojis as input in Python?

Tags: python, input, emoji

This is a code for telegram bot. I want the bot say "Hi" when the user writes "x" or send "" emoji. It works when the user writes x, but nothing happens when send .

I use `pythoneverywhere.com` as host and run my code in its console.

```py
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#coding=UTF-8

from telegram.ext import Updater, Filters, MessageHandler
from telegram import ParseMode , InputTextMessageContent
from emoji import emojize

updater = Updater("928344838:AAGUaVBq2ZTfqM059MZ1WXRFELb3EaEUkZw")

def msg_filter(bot , update):
    words = ['x','']

    if any (i in update.message.text for i in words):
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = "Hi")

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, msg_filter))

updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: Provide `repr(update.message.text)` and `repr(words)`.

Comment: it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that pythoneverywhere or telegram is displaying text using an encoding that doesn't support emojis. Python unicode strings natively support emojis, so I don't think it's a Python issue.